# How to increment a value in a loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I'm not sure how to properly write the question. So, the idea I have is to print the original random values I get from a list. After the user inputs a `1` inside a while loop it creates one new random number from the list. Every time the user enters `1` as the input, it keeps creating a new random number and prints the previous random numbers together.

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random_number = [random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(2)]
print(random_number)

while True:
    choice = int(input("Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: "))
    if choice == 2:
        break

    elif choice == 1:
        extra_number = [random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(1)]
        for i in extra_number:
            print("\nFirst Numbers:", random_number, "Extra Numbers:", i)
```

This loop will return a random number from the list. However, every time the user enters `1` it replaces the old one with a new one. I want to still return those old values and also print a new one every time the user enters `1`. So, I thought that maybe increment will work, but I don't know how to make it work. I also tried `enumerate` and `range(len())` and found it a bit confusing to understand. I would appreciate it if someone could help me or if there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: you are creating new list each time. instead you can add the element to list or use `list.extend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question. Here I added the list old_numbers where you save the pervious values.

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
old_numbers=[]


while True:
    choice = int(input("Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: "))
    if choice == 2:
        break

    elif choice == 1:
        extra_number = random.choice(numbers)
        old_numbers.append(extra_number)
        print("\nFirst Numbers:", old_numbers, "Extra Numbers:", extra_number)
```

The result:

> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3] Extra Numbers: 3
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4] Extra Numbers: 4
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4] Extra Numbers: 4
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1] Extra Numbers: 1
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2] Extra Numbers: 2
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3] Extra Numbers: 3
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3] Extra Numbers: 3
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3] Extra Numbers: 3
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4] Extra Numbers: 4
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 1
>
> First Numbers: [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4] Extra Numbers: 4
>
> Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: 2

Comment: Yes, that's it. I forgot that I could just have an empty list and just append it to that.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random_number = [random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(2)]
extra_numbers = []
print(random_number)

while True:
    choice = int(input("Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: "))
    if choice == 2:
        break

    elif choice == 1:
        extra_number = random.choice(numbers)
        extra_numbers.append(extra_number)
        print("\nFirst Numbers:", random_number, "Extra Numbers:", extra_numbers)
```

Comment: That does work. Although, I wanted the extra numbers to print separated from the random_number (original list). Such as `First Numbers: [2, 5] Extra Numbers [1, 3]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer anyways. This is also very nice to know.

Comment: Welcome. Adding an edit above which does that.

Comment: Once again thank you for the answer. I had to accept the other answer since it was given with what I wanted. If I could choose yours too I would have done that.